# Why do I have to cast an instance of a class to Self to match the return type?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I've got the following code that generates a compiler error.
It's easy to workaround (via as! Self), but I don't understand why I need to -- is it a compiler deficiency or is there something going on with protocols I should learn :)

Thanks for any tips.

```
protocol Foo {
  func getAbar() -> Self
}

final class Bar : Foo {
  func getAbar() -> Self {
    // if I change the following line to:
    // return Bar() as! Self
    // then it compiles
    // otherwise it generates the following error:
    // Cannot convert return expression of type 'Bar' to return type 'Self'
    return Bar()
  }
}

Bar().getAbar()
```

Comment: I think it will work when you replace `-> Self` with `-> Bar` (or another concrete type) when implementing the protocol.

Comment: Or `return Self()`

Comment: I think this has to do with you using a class, a struct will not generate this error and if you remove the protocol conformance from the class you still get the same error. Possibly something related to inheritance but I am not sure.

Comment: @Sulthan -- thanks, I tried that when I was first writing this code, but at that time, I hadn't made the Bar class final, so in that case, returning Bar wasn't sufficient, because Bar wouldn't be Self for a subclass.  I didn't think to try it again after making the class final.  I'll update my question -- and happy to accept an answer from you if you want to write one up :)

Comment: It would be better to roll back the edit in which you basically answer the question and instead post it as an answer. You can even accept your own answer so that the question won't appear to still need an answer.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson -- thanks -- it's definitely related to inheritance -- see my Edit above -- the possibility of subclassing Bar is what led me to this problem in the first place.  I didn't have Bar being final at first.

Comment: @Caleb -- thanks, I'll do that.

Comment: well I was starting to, but it got closed as a duplicate -- I did look for an answer, and that duplicate is a good answer, but I failed to find it :)

Comment: That duplicate is not actually the best answer - it's old. It was not possible to use `-> Self` outside protocols then. Actually, I have no idea why `-> Self` is different than `-> Bar` in the context of a final class.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `Bar().getAbar()` doesn't make a lot of sense... you're creating an instance of `Bar` in order to call a function that just creates an instance of `Bar`.

Comment: I closed this question because of a comment from OP that made me convinced that the duplicate was good enough even though I first discarded it as such since it didn’t contain an explanation. I have no problem if someone reopens  this again. @caleb what if we see this as a copy function for instance, then it makes more sense to me.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Sure -- there are certainly good reasons to use `Self` as a return type -- I only meant to point out that the OP's specific example is kind of nonsensical. Also, I think it's fine that you closed it -- it does seem like a duplicate, and if the accepted answer on the dupe is out of date then it'd be better to just update that answer or write a new one for that question.

Comment: @Caleb -- yeh my question wasn't really meant to make sense from the perspective of why you'd implement this specific code -- but as a very simplified version that contained the essence of a problem I was trying to understand -- which I do much better now :)